# How do you traverse the DOM in React Server Components, with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

Hope you're having a good day.

Pre Next 13, I'd wrap my default _app.tsx component with a development helper function that would add a small 2px button to every component in the tree.

It was fairly straightforward, but now the structure of the children and props seem more complex. Can't find any documentation about it. Anybody know where to start?

```js
import React from 'react';

// Defines a higher-order component (HOC) that adds a dot to a component
const withDot = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return function ComponentWithDot(props) {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'inline-block', marginRight: '4px' }}>
        <span style={{ fontSize: '12px' }}>•</span>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </div>
    );
  };
};

// Recursively wrap all components in the tree with the withDot HOC
const wrapComponentsWithDot = (Component) => {
  return function WrappedComponentWithDot(props) {
    const Wrapped = withDot(Component);
    return <Wrapped {...props} />;
  };
};

// Wrap the _app.tsx component with wrapComponentsWithDot
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const WrappedComponent = wrapComponentsWithDot(Component);

  return <WrappedComponent {...pageProps} />;
}
```

Comment: First, it doesn't look like you are traversing the DOM, just adding a wrapper to your component within the application (might be a good idea to correct the question ;). Second, I don't believe that Server component have access to the DOM but I don't think you need to either.  Not sure how it actually would work but I guess you can try adding it to the root layout file.

Comment: Edited, thanks.